# Crystal report - Display page number as 1 of 2 and 2 of 2 and so on

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

I need to display the page number in the crystal report as
1 of 2
2 of 2 ......
and so on

I tried many ways but it didn't work out
Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Simply drag 'Page N of M' from the list under 'Special Fields' in field explorer onto the report canvas.

Comment: Thank you so much I have done the way you have told but it displays as Page 1of 2. I want to remove the word Page and display only 1 of 2.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, create and use this formula to display the desired result:

```
ToText(PageNumber,0) & " of " & ToText(TotalPageCount,0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Can we do supercript in crystal report? I have some words which I need to do some super script. Please help me on this